# Input & Label Do Not Vertically Align - Different Element Widths

Tags: html, css, reactjs

What's the reason the inputs do not align with the button and other elements?

Layout (Firefox Developer Edition) shows that the sizes of input and label elements differ even though they are in the same div.

[image]

What causes this? And how to align them in an elegant way (without changing margin through trial and error for example)?

Relevant section of NewTransaction.js file:
[image]

CSS file of NewTransaction:
[image]

SOURCE CODE: https://github.com/yanichik/react-course/tree/main/full-course/expense-tracker-v2

Comment: can you fork that up in code sandbox

Comment: @Viira here's the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/expense-tracker-yan-bc5zp

Comment: I have added my answer @brunshte

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the input element has padding of 2px on both left and right, and as default in user agent stylesheet, [box-sizing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) is set to `content-box`.

> content-box gives you the default CSS box-sizing behavior. If you set
> an element's width to 100 pixels, then the element's content box will
> be 100 pixels wide, and the width of any border or padding will be
> added to the final rendered width, making the element wider than
> 100px.

You should use `box-sizing: border-box` to overcome this issue.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp

Your updated code: https://codesandbox.io/embed/expense-tracker-yan-forked-80tfk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Answer (score 1):

It's better to normalize the styles,

in your code the style that made problem was `box-sizing`, I just set for all element to `border-box`, however you can just add `box-sizing: border-box;` to input and it works too.

```css
html {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*::before,
*::after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: inherit;
  -moz-box-sizing: inherit;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.form {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

input {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}

label {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

button {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: purple;
  border-color: purple;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.amount,
.description {
  /* display: flex; */
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div className="form">
  <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
    <div class='description'>
      <label htmlFor="description" pointing="true">
                        Description
                    </label>
      <input type="text" id='description' placeholder="Type Something" ref={descrRef}/>
    </div>
    <div class='amount'>
      <label htmlFor="amount" pointing="true">
                        Amount
                    </label>
      <input type="number" id='amount' step="0.01" placeholder="$" ref={amountRef} />
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit">Add Transaction</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```